# How to import version number from Android gradle build into Jenkins variable?

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, versioning

My goal is to print out somewhere on my Jenkins project page what the last version was that got built. To be clear, if I have the following in my manifest:

```
android:versionName="1.4.43"
```

I'd like to print out a little blurb somewhere that says:

```
Last version: 1.4.43
```

Has anybody done something like this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see your Version name in the console output ?

if so you can use description setter plug in to display the version, on the build history. is that what you want to do ?

https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Description+Setter+Plugin